# Pinia nested array in v-for not updating on ajax request Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, pinia

I have a SheetItemsStore (Pinia) with:

```
const sheetItems = ref([])

function getSheetItems() {
    return axios.get(route('sheet-items.index', {'balance': balance.value.id})).then((response) => {
            sheetItems.value = response.data
    })
}
```

And i have a view:

```
<script setup>
import {UseBalanceStore} from "@/Stores/UseBalanceStore.js";
import {UseSheetItemsStore} from "@/Stores/UseSheetItemsStore.js";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import {UseCategoriesStore} from "@/Stores/UseCategoriesStore.js";

const balanceStore = UseBalanceStore()
const sheetItemStore = UseSheetItemsStore()
const categoriesStore = UseCategoriesStore()

function updateReferenceDate(value) {
    axios.patch(route('balances.reference-date.update', {balance: balanceStore.balance.id}), {increase: value}).then(function () {
        balanceStore.getBalance()
        balanceStore.getGrandTotal()
        categoriesStore.getCategories()
        sheetItemStore.getSheetItems()
    })
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex mt-2 mb-2">
        <span class="mt-3 mr-2">Peildatum: {{ balanceStore.balance.reference_date }}</span>
        <PrimaryButton class="mr-2" @click="updateReferenceDate(false)">Maand achteruit</PrimaryButton>
        <PrimaryButton class="mr-2" @click="updateReferenceDate(true)">Maand Vooruit</PrimaryButton>
    </div>
</template>
```

As you can see my sheetItemsStore.getSheetItems gets triggered. I verified this. The Ajax call is working. But it is a nested array and nested properties get updated but the following v-for is not responding to the fact that sheetItemsStore.sheetItems is updated:

```
<div v-for="category in sheetItemsStore.sheetItems" :key="category.id" :tabindex="category.id" class="card sheet-items-container">
      <div class="flex justify-between card-title">
            <span class="font-bold w-full">{{ category.name.toUpperCase() }}</span>
            <delete-button v-if="editMode" @click="deleteCategory(category)"/>
      </div>

      <div class="sheet-items-list">
           <sheet-item v-for="sheetItem in category.sheet_items"
                   :key="sheetItem.id"
                   :edit-mode="editMode"
                   :sheet-item="sheetItem"
           />
      </div>
 </div>
```

The updates are in properties of a sheetItem in category.sheet_items. In vue you need to specify "deep: true" with a watcher. Is there something like that going on here? How can i make the v-for update?

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddeling i found out a good solution. I change my store to:

```
function getSheetItems() {
   return axios.get(route('sheet-items.index', {'balance': balance.value.id})).then((response) => {
            if (sheetItems.value.length) {
                sheetItems.value.forEach((category, key) => {
                    category.sheet_items.forEach((sheetItem, index) => {
                      sheetItem.count = response.data[key].sheet_items[index].count
                      sheetItem.amount = response.data[key].sheet_items[index].amount
                      sheetItem.total = response.data[key].sheet_items[index].total
                })
            })
        } else {
            sheetItems.value = response.data
        }
    })
}
```

This way the reactivity stays and i only do 1 ajax request. Next i listen to those changes, also keeping reactivity

```
watch(props.sheetItem, (oldSheetItem, newSheetItem) => {
    form.count = props.sheetItem.count
    form.total = props.sheetItem.total
})
```

And my form is properly updated, problem solved